# PulseAudio: how to disable a device on startup?

Tags: pulseaudio

I have a pulseaudio configuration where I send audio from my system to a remote system for output using module-rtp-send. I don't want any local soundcards to output by default.  I've disabled my motherboard's audio in the BIOS, but the audio provided by my GPU (via HDMI/DisplayPort) is still present.  I've placed a Pulse configuration similar to the following in my ~/.config/pulse/default.pa:

```
.include /etc/pulse/default.pa

# Create a null sink
load-module module-null-sink sink_name=DesktopSpeakers

# Give the sink a pretty name
update-sink-proplist DesktopSpeakers device.description="Desktop Speakers"

# Set it as default
set-default-sink DesktopSpeakers

# Create a connection to the network'd system, and send any audio from the null sink there
load-module module-rtp-send destination_ip="192.168.0.20" source=DesktopSpeakers.monitor format="s16be" rate=44100 channels=2

# Disable the AMDGPU's audio
set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_0a_00.1 off
```

I'm having a problem where the GPU's audio is still enabled even after adding the "set-card-profile" in the PA config as shown above.  This is causing my network audio sink to be ignored when I first login (Plasma desktop on Xorg). If I either run "systemctl --user restart pulseaudio" or run "pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_0a_00.1 off", the network audio sink works fine.

Why is the set-card-profile line in my default.pa not disabling the GPU audio on startup (but seemingly only when starting pulse on graphical session login)?